# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file, stateful spark structured streaming with kafka

Tags: scala, spark-structured-streaming, spark-window-function

We are running a stateful structured streaming job which reads from Kafka and writes to HDFS. And we are hitting this exception:

```
17/12/08 05:20:12 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 4, hcube1-1n03.eng.hortonworks.com, executor 1):
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error reading delta file /checkpointDir/state/0/0/1.delta of HDFSStateStoreProvider[id = (op=0, part=0), dir = /checkpointDir/state/0/0]: /checkpointDir/state/0/0/1.delta does not exist at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$updateFromDeltaFile(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:410) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:362) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:358) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:360) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.state.HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$sql$execution$streaming$state$HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider$$loadMap$1$$anonfun$6.apply(HDFSBackedStateStoreProvider.scala:359) at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121
```

Of course, the file doesn't exist in HDFS. And in the state/0/0 directory there is no file at all. While we have some files in the commits and offsets folders. I am not sure about the reason of this behavior. It seems to happen on the second time the job is started

Comment: can you share the code?

Comment: I m reading data through kafka with spark windowing operation m trying to find latest data with timestamp through spark window function and row_number then save dataframe in hive table. val sparkSession: SparkSession =
SparkSession.builder().appName(SPARK_APP_NAME)

.config("hive.metastore.warehouse.dir", SPARK_HIVE_WAREHOUSE_DIR_SUSPICIOUS_USER)
// .config("spark.default.parallelism",70)
.config("hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode", "nonstrict")
.config("hive.support.concurrency", true)
.config("spark.sql.orc.impl","native")
.config("spark.speculation","false")

Comment: @ 
Emiliano Martinez  sure but how to share the code